# Android browser touchend event bug workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, mobile-website, android-browser

I've been developing a mobile site for my homepage and I have run into an issue when hooking into mobile touchevents. Basically I would like to accomplish the following:

1. User scrolls down
2. on touchend event is fired -->  a function is called to figure out the amount of the document that is hidden above after the scroll (like jQuery scrollTop)
3. program takes action based on the amount of the document that is hidden up top

My issues are the following. So touchend works like expected in iOS, when the user lifts her finger the function makes a call to jQuery.scrollTop() which gives me a pixel value for how much the user has scrolled down. However on Android Browser devices it seems that the jQuery.scrollTop() value is calculated on touchstart. That is to say the event doesn't fire off properly, I get the correct pageX & Y coordinates from the touchend event, however scrolltop() returns the value from when the user started scrolling. I've checked around on the inet and this seems to be a known android browser bug, what I want to know is if there a decent workaround for this issue i.e. one that doesn't involve preventing the default scroll behaviour!? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking into account smooth scrolling? or just basic scrolling?
With basic scrolling you should be able to get the correct value simply by using document.body.scrollTop

Let me know if there is an issue